# How do I mount my home partition as /var/www/vhosts?

Tags: partitioning, mount

```
Warning: Changing vhosts directory with the SELinux enabled in Plesk will break websites. This is due to SELinux limitation: it stores absolute paths in its policies, /var/www/vhosts, in this case. As a workaround, set SELinux to permissive mode before applying steps below.
After changing vhosts folder, SELinux should be kept in the permissive mode for correct websites working capacity. As an alternative workaround, mount new partition as /var/www/vhosts.
```

Hi, I am very new to Linux and I need help. How do I mount my /home partition as /var/www/vhosts.

## More explanation posted as an answer:

I have PLESk installed on server. I thought PLESK web sites will be stored in `/home` where I had a lot of space, But unfortunately it was stored on my root partition. So now root is full. After that I searched about it and found this article
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213367009

According their instructions using this script:

```
plesk bin transvhosts.pl --dest-dir /home --correct-script
```

I have moved all the domain names to `/home` partition.

So the above article
says After changing vhosts folder, SELinux should be kept in the permissive mode for correct websites working capacity. So there are two options:

1. Permanently disable SElinux
2. Other option is the one that I'm trying to do.

Comment: You don't. Very bad idea to do so. And you don't mount but you can symlink your -website- directory.